# Slider settings for GPUImage

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, gpuimage

I'm making an app which allows the user to apply GPUImage filters to still photos using a UISlider. I'd like for the slider to initially start at the zero point for each filter (i.e. the value at which none of the filter has been applied yet) and I'm wondering how this can be determined? I've used some of the values that are listed in the GPUImage documentation and for certain sliders they start at 0, but others it's hard to determine (and for some, the min and max values are way off for me). The values for something like GPUImagePosterizeFilter seem to be way off for me (set min to 1, max to 128 and initial to 1). I've also checked some of the values in the FilterShowcase test project which are different than the documentation, but still don't always start at 0. Am I just completely missing the point here? Or is there some setting I maybe have to turn on to be in line with the slider values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might have been approaching this the wrong way. Rather than looking for a "zero point" on a filter, I think I should focus on applying the filter only when the user applies it, and trying to find a good starting point that is close to how the image looks without the filter for the initial value on the slider.

Comment: One thing that might be a useful addition to the base framework would be a passthrough switch on each filter that would allow you to turn it on or off without ripping it out of the filter chain. That wouldn't provide the gradual easing you're looking for, but could be handy in enabling or disabling effects as needed. A few people have requested this, but I haven't had the time to add it yet.

Comment: @BradLarson - that would definitely be a nice luxury. Even so GPUImage is so much more convenient than CoreImage. On CoreImage you have to keep attaching the filters every time you change the value of a filter. Thanks again for the great job!

Answer (score 0):

Nope, no setting for this. All I can really recommend is that to make this as efficient as possible make a switch statement in a single method and determine what to do by index of the currently selected filter.

From there, I would leave the min/max values of the slider the same so that you don't have to animate from one calculated point to another if the filter changes and mathematically convert the slider's value into units that the current filter understands. i.e. 0-1 --> 1-128

Comment: One of these days, I might add some kind of a readable property for suggested min, max, and default values, but even that would be tricky in cases. For example, many filters support multiple settings or non-float types (like matrices), so having a single value as the readout from this will be problematic. That's why I have all the switch cases in the FilterShowcase example.

Comment: Also, I've really fallen behind in updating the documentation to reflect the changes I and others have made in the various filters, as well as make sure all filters are listed there.

Comment: @BradLarson I recently did some switch related stuff using GPUImage, and it may not be the best way, but with how much of time using GPUImage saved me it was hard to complain. And that solution could work. Even if it was just a description-ish string, like `-[GPUImageFilter filterDescription]` it could be helpful.

Comment: @BradLarson - Thanks for the reply Brad, and thanks for making this great framework. Do you have a paypal so I could make a donation? As for my question, I do have a switch statement for my filters, and I'm basing the slider values on your values either in the documentation or FilterShowcase. I do understand the settings may not be up to date, what I'm wondering is, is there a manual way to find the "0" point for a slider? (i.e. when you apply the filter to a photo, and it does absolutely nothing because it's at its lowest point?

Comment: @BradLarson - Just trying to find that point so when the user starts filtering the photo, it appears like it is making a smooth transition from not having a filter to having one applied. I think I can figure out the min / max values through trial and error, though would you happen to know a more precise way to find those as well?

Comment: @0x7fffffff - I do have a switch statement that defines values for each filter, which I'm totally fine with. I'm not complaining about the fact that there is no meta data like in CoreImage, could care less about that. Just having trouble figuring out the "0" point, or when you apply the filter to the photo and it does nothing. As Rob said, he hasn't had time to update some of the values, so was wondering if there was a precise way to calculate these on my own (or what would be the best way to go about figuring this?).

Comment: @CoDEFRo - Not all filters have such a 0 point. Edge detectors, false color filtering, etc. are either on or not and their values adjust the look of the filter. In most cases, I set the default to a value that I felt would be the most common starting point, rather than the equivalent of being off.

Comment: @BradLarson - Thanks Brad. Think I need to change my approach to this based on what you're saying. Also, can I make a donation? Really appreciate the work you've done on this.